# Why is the Ternary operator not working inside a method argument in java

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I got this noted in a middle of a development.

Why is the Ternary operator not working inside a method argument? Here it is clearly `InputStream` or (else) `String`.

```
class A{

    public  static boolean opAlpha(InputStream inputStream) {

        // Do something

        return true;

    }

    public static boolean opAlpha(String arg) {

        // Do something else

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        boolean useIsr = true;

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String arg = null;

//      boolean isTrue = useIsr ? A.opAlpha(inputStream): A.opAlpha(arg); // This is OK.
        boolean isTrue =  A.opAlpha(useIsr ? inputStream : arg); // This is not. (Error : The method opAlpha(InputStream) in the type A is not applicable for the arguments (Object))

    }

}
```

Comment: No operator overloading here.

Comment: And my usual pedantic comment: It's not the ternary operator, it's the [*conditional operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25). It's true that it's **a** ternary operator (an operator that accepts three operands), and it's true that it's the only one Java has, but in theory there could be others at some point... :-)

Comment: Thanks T.J. Got your point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `useIsr ? inputStream : arg` is of type `Object`, since that's the common type of `inputStream` (`InputStream`) and `arg` (`String`).

You don't have any `opAlpha` method that accepts an `Object`. Hence the compilation error.

Comment: @Namalak `That means it is because it calls the methods depending on the Class type. Not the object type`. I don't know what you mean by that. If you meant that it calls the methods depending on the compile time type of the arguments and not the runtime type then you are correct. The compiler decides at compile time which overloaded version of the method will be called.

Comment: That is true Eran. Forgot the general method overloading principles for a while. I deleted my comment once I noted that. I didn't note your comment when delete it. I'll try to let it diaplay again since you have replied that. Thank you anyway for the answer. It cleared me through!

Answer (score 10):

The compiler needs to decide which overloaded method it should call in your `main` method. The method call must be placed in the compiled bytecode of `main` and not decided at runtime.

In fact, even though *you* know that the type of conditional expression is either `InputStream` or `String`, the compiler sees its type as `Object`. From [Section 15.25.3 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.3):

> A reference conditional expression is a poly expression if it appears in an assignment context or an invocation context (§5.2. §5.3). Otherwise, it is a standalone expression.
>
> Where a poly reference conditional expression appears in a context of a particular kind with target type T, its second and third operand expressions similarly appear in a context of the same kind with target type T.
>
> The type of a poly reference conditional expression is the same as its target type.
>
> The type of a standalone reference conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
> - If the type of one of the second and third operands is the null type, and the type of the other operand is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.
> - **Otherwise, the second and third operands are of types S1 and S2 respectively. Let T1 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S1, and let T2 be the type that results from applying boxing conversion to S2. The type of the conditional expression is the result of applying capture conversion (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2)**.

where `lub(T1, T2)` stands for ["Least Upper Bound"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.4) of types `T1` and `T2`. The least upper bound type of `InputStream` and `String` is `Object`.

Comment: Thank you manouti. Your answer is very informative and I strongly believe SOF must have an option to accept more than one answer